# SF Short Story - Nature Rebels

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As with many of my questions, this American short story appeared in an anthology during the 1960s, a decade in which I devoured science fiction. All I can remember is that a group of Earthers (miners, I believe) have established a base on an extra-solar planet. A primitive local tribe demonstrates near the base, saying the miners are disturbing nature and nature will have its revenge. Nature does have its revenge - the planet is shaken by a series of convulsions that kill everyone, the natives included. Before they are destroyed the horrified Earthers discover that there is a universe-wide natural pogrom against all intelligent life.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

["The Mountain Without a Name"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71163), a short story by [Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley).
You may have read it in his collection [*Citizen in Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?38466).

**All I can remember is that a group of Earthers (miners, I believe) have established a base on an extra-solar planet.**

Developers preparing the planet for human settlement. The construction boss, Morrison, is behind schedule, on account of a series of accidents:

> "Yes sir," Morrison admitted unwillingly. "We've had a run of bad luck. But we'll roll."
>
> "I hope so," Mr. Shotwell said. "I certainly hope so. You've been there nearly a month, and you haven't built a single city, or port, or even a highway! Our first advertisements have appeared. Inquiries are rolling in. There are people who want to settle there, Morrison! Businesses and service industries to move in."

**A primitive local tribe demonstrates near the base, saying the miners are disturbing nature and nature will have its revenge.**

> Three natives were standing at the North Gate beside the camp interpreter. They were of human-related stock, scrawny, naked stone-age savages.
>
> "What do they want?" Morrison asked.
>
> The interpreter said, "Well, Mr. Morrison, boiling it down, they've changed their minds. They want their planet back, and they're willing to return all our presents."
>
> [. . .]
>
> "They say they've changed their minds," the interpreter said. "To render it idiomatically, they say we are to return to our demonland in the sky or they will destroy us with strong magic. The sacred drums are weaving the curse now, and the spirits are gathering."

**Before they are destroyed the horrified Earthers discover that there is a universe-wide natural pogrom against all intelligent life.**

> "I think the planet didn't want us any more," Morrison said. "I think it had enough."
>
> "I got Earth!" the radio operator called. "Go ahead, Morrie."
>
> "Shotwell? Listen, we can't stick it out," Morrison said into the receiver. "I'm getting my men out of here while there's still time. I can't explain it to you now—I don't know if I'll ever be able to—"
>
> "The planet can't be used at all?" Shotwell asked.
>
> "No. Not a chance. Sir; I hope this doesn't jeopardize the firm's standing—"
>
> "Oh, to hell with the firm's standing," Mr. Shotwell said. "It's just that—you don't know what's been going on here, Morrison. You know our Gobi project? In ruins, every bit of it. And it's not just us. I don't know. You'll have to excuse me, I'm not speaking coherently, but since Australia sank—"
>
> "What?"
>
> "Yes, sank, sank I tell you. Perhaps we should have suspected something with the hurricanes. But then the earthquakes—but we just don't know any more."
>
> "But Mars? Venus? Alpha Centauri?"
>
> "The same everywhere. But we can't be through, can we, Morrison? I mean, Mankind—"

Comment: That is it! I have just ordered a copy. Thanks again!